# What is iTunesHelper?

Tags: macos, itunes

In my account settings under `Login` there is an app called iTunesHelper. What does this app do? Can I remove it from the login apps without affecting iTunes, or will it be put back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a program that launches iTunes whenever an iPhone/iPod/iPad is plugged in. If I recall correctly, if you remove it, iTunes will no longer automatically launch when an iPhone/iPod/iPad is plugged in.

Comment: I have this disabled for all my iPods and iPads so I guess I can safely remove it from the list?

Comment: @RadekS: Yes, you can.

Comment: @RadekS: Yes, you can remove it, but future updates of iTunes may bring it back, so keep an eye on it.